# How to save post title before publish?

Tags: custom-post-types

How to save post title before publish?
 I want save post title before publish post in costume post type

Comment: The title is saved automatically, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Why do you want to do this and have you done any research in the topic?

Comment: @fuxia I know the title is saved automatically but in post but i have created custome post and then i do not fill any data then after click on publish title blank when page load after and i have post title before publish post